# Struts2 Date Tag TimeZone behavior

Tags: java, date, struts2, timezone, utc

I am using `<s:date>` tag of struts2.

To convert a date stored `04/09/2014 11:40:17` in UTC time  to `IST` time I used struts2 `date` tag as belows :

```xml
<s:date name = "dateregistered" 
      format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a" 
    timezone = "GMT+5.30" />
```

and it always give me the date: `04/09/2014 06:10:17 AM`.

The expected result should be: `04/09/2014 05:10:17 PM`.

I am not getting where I am wrong and doing mistake,I am using `hibernate` to fetch and `java.util.date` to store the value which is used above

**The process how data was stored and retrived:**

I stored value in mysql through hibernate:

```xml
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
user.setCreatedDateTime(new java.util.Date());
...
...
...
```

Now I am getting the value from DB as `04/09/2014 11:40:17` . When I performed this insertion the actual time was `04/09/2014 05:10:17 PM` `IST` . So it clears that the time being stored in DB is UTC time.

Now I am retriving time and setting in map in key value pair as `map.put("dateregistered",c.getCreatedDateTime());`

```xml
user.getCreatedDateTime()
```

and retrieving value using struts 2 tag as mentioned above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `:` instead of `.` as separator;
2. Add a leading `0`.

The right TimeZone for [IST (Indian Standard Time)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Standard_Time) is [`UTC+05:30`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC+5:30), then `GMT+05:30`;

```xml
<s:date name = "dateregistered" 
      format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a" 
    timezone = "GMT+05:30" />
```